# Trying to find a way to emulate a hover design I saw on Pinterest

Tags: javascript, css

On pinterest, when you hover an image, it darkens and shows some details of the poster. But when you move the cursor away from the image, this hover effect seems to stay for a very short period. When you move your cursor over many images, it even creates a small trail of darkened images due to this delay. However, there seems to be no delay or transition for when the hover effect starts.

Can this be done in CSS? I'm not sure how to delay just the exit of a hover animation.

I'm pretty new to web dev, hope the description makes sense! :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Such "delay" effects can be done by CSS.

To start your studies on an living object (good idea!) you should learn to read the online code.
For example in Firefox (on PC, not android or IOS!) you have nice possibilities for analytics:

When found a webpage of interest press the key combination  `ctrl` `shift` `I` to open the "inspector" of the developer tools.

Here you can select the objects, view their CSS attributes and even change them (only for your local current view) to see, what of these things make the effect you're interested in.

So have some fun and if there is an detailed thing you can't understand come here, show the sample code and ask.

Have fun!